# What is the meaning of colon, underscore and star in lift's SiteMap(entries:_*)?

Tags: scala, lift

I'm learning [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) and [lift](http://liftweb.com) at the same time and I got stuck on understanding the syntax used to inintialize the [SiteMap](http://wiki.liftweb.net/index.php/SiteMap) in the Boot.scala:

```
 val entries = Menu(Loc("Home", "/", "Home")) :: 
       Menu(Loc("Foo", "/badger", "Foo")) ::
       Menu(Loc("Directory Foo", "/something/foo", "Directory Foo")) :: Nil 
 LiftRules.setSiteMap(SiteMap(entries:_*))
```

What exactly is the meaning of the SiteMap parameter?
I see that the value *entries* is a list of Menu. What is the **colon, underscore, star**?
At first I thought it is a method on the List, but I am unable to find such definition...

Comment: It's actually a pretty good question. I bet a lot of people face the same problem, which was, as you pointed out in your anwer, exarcebated by the lack of space between : and "_".

Answer (score 78, accepted):

OK, after my colleague mentioned to me, that he encountered this secret incantation in the [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed) book, I did a search in my copy and found it described in *Section 8.8 Repeated parameters*. (Though you need to search with space between the colon and underscore :-/ ) There is a one sentence to explain it as:

> ... append the array argument with a colon and an **`_*`** symbol, like this: 
>   `scala> echo(arr: _*)`
>
> This notation tells the compiler to pass each element of `arr` as its own argument to `echo`, rather than all of it as a single argument.

I find the [description offered here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160410161417/http://blog.darevay.com/2009/01/remedial-scala-repeated-parameters-and-initializing-collections/) more helpful.

So `x: _*` is *like* a type declaration that tells the compiler to treat `x` as **repeated parameter** (aka variable-length argument list — ***vararg***).

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude. I'd wish I could find more explanations of this kind here.

Comment: So if you're familiar with Python, calling a function with *var does something similar:

`var=(1, 2, 3)
def f(*args):
  for arg in args:
    print arg
f(*var)`

That will print:
1
2
3

So apparently `x: _*` is Scala's equivalent to this.