# Scala Slick Bulk Insert with Array

Tags: scala, slick

I'm splitting a long string into an array of strings, then I want to insert all of them to the database. I can easily loop through the array and insert one by one, but it seems very inefficient. Then I think there is a `insertAll()` method. However, the `insertAll()` method is defined like this:

`def insertAll(values: U*)`

This only accepts multiple U, but not an `Array` or `List`.

```
/* Insert a new Tag  */
def insert(insertTags: Array[String])(implicit s: Session) {
  var insertSeq: List[Tag] = List()
  for(tag <- insertTags) {
    insertSeq ++= new Tag(None, tag)
  }
  Tag.insertAll(insertSeq)

}
```

*`Tag` is the table Object

This is the preliminary code I have written. It doesn't work because `insertAll()` doesn't take `Seq`. I hope there is a way to do this...so it won't generate an array length times SQL insertion clause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a function expect repeated parameters such as U* and you want to pass a sequence of U instead, it must be marked as a sequence argument, which is done with `: _*` as in

```
Tag.insertAll(insertSeq: _*)
```

This is described in the specification in section 6.6. It disambiguates some situations such as ;

```
def f(x: Any*)
f(Seq(1, "a"))
```

There, f could be called with a single argument, `Seq(1, "a")` or two, `1` and `"a"`. It will be the former, the latter is done with f(Seq(1, "a"): _*). Python has a similar syntax.

---

Regarding the questions in your comment : 
It works with Seq, collections that confoms to Seq, and values that can be implicitly converted to Seqs (which includes Arrays). This means a lot of collections, but not all of them. For instances, Set are not allowed (but they have a toSeq methods so it is still easy to call with a Set).

It is not a method, it it more like a type abscription. It simply tells the compiler that this the argument is the full expected Seq in itself, and not the only item in a sequence argument.

Comment: Does this `: _*` sequence argument marker only apply to `Seq` or does it apply to some other collections as well? How does `: _*` this work if you don't mind me asking? Is it a method? A built in iteration of sort?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124099/what-is-the-meaning-of-colon-underscore-and-star-in-lifts-sitemapentries and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124099/what-is-the-meaning-of-colon-underscore-and-star-in-lifts-sitemapentries.